# 'CheckBox' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox' and 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am editing my web application with the class `ToolTip` which is coming from the namespace `System.Windows.Forms`; There are a few checkboxes in my code and because of this it is displaying this error:

> 'CheckBox' is an ambiguous reference between
>   `System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox` and
>   `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox1`

What should I do to run this tooltip in my web application

Comment: Winforms Tooltips work with WebForms controls?

Comment: Why are you not using the one from WebControls? Is there some sort of limitation?

Comment: @ebad86 Yes there are some limitation there are 90-100 forms so I need to take a ToolTip class. otherwise i will  have to edit all my buttons for that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that u have referenced `System.Web.UI.WebControls` and `System.Windows.Forms` in the `using`-section. If you need both you can use checkbox explicit from `System.Web.UI.WebControls` by saying:

```
using CheckBox = System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox
```

Comment: Error Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton' to 'string'

Comment: and i am passing    toolTip1.Show(btnAdd, "Click me to Add"); so now what should i do?

Comment: As `t3hn00b` wrote: if you only need ToolTip from WebControls/Forms then use it like I wrote in my answer. But it is dependent on what you need out of each namespace. Edit your answer and show what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the full path/name for the checkbox depending on which one you need.
If you want the checkbox from WinForms for instance you would write System.Web.UI.WebControls.Checkbox in your code instead of just Checkbox.

Also check why you are using the System.Windows.Forms namespace in a web app.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the using of `System.Windows.Forms` and use the ToolTip as `System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip` if it's the only thing you need from there.