# Control is an ambigious reference between System.Web.UI.Control and System.Windows.Forms.Control error for Textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I want to clear `textboxes` values on `button click`, but When I write the below code, I get error as

> Control is an ambigious reference between System.Web.UI.Control and System.Windows.Forms.Control.

Here is my code:-

```
public void CleartextBoxes(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control x in parent.Controls)
    {
        if ((x.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)))
        {
            ((TextBox)(x)).Text = "";
        }
        if (x.HasControls())
        {
            CleartextBoxes(x);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a link from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095668/checkbox-is-an-ambiguous-reference-between-system-web-ui-webcontrols-checkbox) but it did not match my requirement. Please suggest any help

Comment: Any particular reason you are referencing `System.Windows.Forms.Control`?

Comment: @JackPettinger: When I Only use `Control` it gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have referenced the libraries `System.Web.UI` and `System.Windows.Forms`. Both the libraries have a class called `Control`. So you have to specify which library you want to use:

```
public void CleartextBoxes(System.Windows.Forms.Control parent)
{
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control x in parent.Controls)
    {
        if ((x.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)))
        {
            ((TextBox)(x)).Text = "";
        }
        if (x.HasChildren)
        {
            CleartextBoxes(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error as **CS0030: Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'** at `((TextBox)(x)).Text = "";`

Comment: Than you need to use `System.Window.Forms`, didn't know which one you were using. I edited my answer.

Comment: now getting error as **'System.Windows.Forms.Control' does not contain a definition for 'HasControls' and no extension method 'HasControls' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)** at line `if (x.HasControls())`

Comment: Come on, don't post every error you get in here, think for yourself. You want a method/property which indicates if the control has children. So you google `System.Windows.Forms.Control`, go to its documentation and look for a method/prop that fits the requirement. Edited my answer.

Comment: sorry for that, but seriously was confused. Thanks a lot for this .;)